# как указать PHPStorm свою JS библиотеку, для того чтобы он видел ее методы?

Tags: javascript, phpstorm

Шторм не видит мою библиотеку, как я не пытался ее подключить глобально. Те библиотека по факту доступна на данной странице в глобальной области и подключать ее надобности нет. 
в настройках в группе Языки и Фреймворки > JS >Libraries добавлял, не помогло(

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/configuring-javascript-libraries.html

Comment: что значит "не видит"?